# Accessing Shadow DOM tree with Selenium, Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom

Is it possible to access elements within a Shadow DOM using Python, Selenium/Chrome webdriver?

Here are my two options. But none of them wor:

file base_page.py:

```js
def expand_shadow_element(self, element):
    """"""
    shadow_root = self.app.driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root

def shadow_click_on_logo(self, locator_shadow_host, locator_shadow_logo):
    """"""
    shadow_host = self._find_element(locator=locator_shadow_host)
    element_shadow_host = self.expand_shadow_element(shadow_host)
    shadow_logo = element_shadow_host._find_element(locator=locator_shadow_logo)
    shadow_logo.click()
```

file navigation.py:

```js
class Navigation(BasePage):
    """"""

    SHADOW_HOST = (By.ID, "live-space")
    SHADOW_CONTENT = (By.ID, "root")
    SHADOW_LOGO = (By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Домой']")

    def click_on_logo(self):
        """"""
        self.shadow_click_on_logo(locator_shadow_host=self.SHADOW_HOST, locator_shadow_logo=self.SHADOW_LOGO)
```

file tests_navigation.py:

```js
class TestNavigation:
    """"""

    def test_click_on_logo(self, app, login_user):
        """"""
        app.navigation.click_on_logo()
```

I end up with an error:
**selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: circular reference**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8jts.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhzBn.png)

**If I try the second option:**

```js
def click_on_logo(self):
    """"""
    self.app.driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div#live-space')."
                           "shadowRoot.querySelector('div#root>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>button')").click()
```

I also get the error, although often:

**selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found**

But the element is in the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xu8z.png)